# Limitation of the sum of the maximum probabilities

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_1,...$ be i.i.d. real random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$,

$S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$,

$X_{i}^{\left( v \right)} :=  X_i \mathbb{1}_{ \left\{ \left| X_i \right| \leq v \right\} } - E [  X_i \mathbb{1}_{ \left\{ \left| X_i \right| \leq v \right\} } ]$,

$S_{i}^{\left( v \right)} := \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} X_i \mathbb{1}_{ \left\{ \left| X_i \right| \leq v \right\} } - E \left[ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} X_i \mathbb{1}_{ \left\{ \left| X_i \right| \leq v \right\} } \right].$

Then we have $S_{a+b}^{\left( v \right)} - S_{b}^{\left( v \right)} = S_{a}^{\left( v \right)}$.

So $S_{a+b}^{\left( v \right)} - S_{b}^{\left( v \right)} $ has the same distribution as $S_{a}^{\left( v \right)} $.

However I don't understand the limiting below which is conclusion of previous fact.

For $n>2^k$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\sum\limits_{j=1}^{2^k} P \left( \max\limits_{(j-1)n2^{-k}\leq i \leq j \lfloor n2^{-k} \rfloor} \left| S_{j \lfloor n2^{-k} \rfloor }^{(v)} - S_{i}^{(v)} \right| \geq \lambda \sqrt{n} \right) 
 \leq 2^k P \left( \max\limits_{1 \leq i \leq \lfloor n2^{-k}\rfloor} \left| S_{i}^{(v)} \geq \lambda \sqrt{n} \right| \right) .
\end{split} 
\end{equation*}

Comment: I do not have more assumptions, it's proof of the Lemma 3.3. from "LECTURE NOTES ON DONSKER’S THEOREM" (https://www.math.utah.edu/~davar/ps-pdf-files/donsker.pdf) and there is also no N(0,1) just i.i.d.

Comment: Ah sorry, you have n>2^k. Your (0,1) without explanation at the beginning is absolutely not clear, you should have precised « with expectation 0 and variance 1 ».

Comment: Ok, sorry. I fixed it.

Comment: I edited the question, which was still badly written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I omit the superscripts (v). I only use the fact that we have i.i.d. random variables.

Set $d = \lfloor n2^{-k} \rfloor$ and $c = \lambda\sqrt{n}$.
For every $j \in [1,2^k]$,
$$[\max_{(j-1)d \le i \le jd} |S_{jd} - S_i| \ge c] = [\max_{0 \le i \le d} |S_{jd} - S_{jd-i}|  \ge c]= [\max_{1 \le i \le d} |S_{jd} - S_{jd-i}|  \ge c].$$
This event have the same probability as $[\max_{1 \le i \le d} |S_i|  \ge c]$
since $(X_{jd},X_{jd-1},\ldots,X_{jd-j+1})$ has the same distribution as $(X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{d})$, so $(S_{jd}-S_{jd-1},\ldots,S_{jd}-S_{jd-j+1})$ has the same distribution as $(S_{1},\ldots,S_{d})$. The result follows by summation over all $j \in [1,2^k]$.

Comment: There should be $P[max |...| \geq c]$ right?

Comment: @nodis6 I wrote first an equality between events, which implies an equAlity between probabilities.